# Rails / Kaminari - How to order a paginated array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, kaminari

I'm having a problem **ordering** an array that I've successfully paginated with Kaminari.

In my controller I have:

```
@things = @friend_things + @user_things

@results = Kaminari.paginate_array(@things).page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

I want to have the final `@results` array ordered by `:created_at`, but have had no luck getting ordering to work with the generic array wrapper that Kaminari provides. Is there a way to set the order in the Kaminari wrapper? Otherwise what would be the best way? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could sort the elements before sending it to Kaminary, like this:

```
@things = @friend_things + @user_things
@things.sort! { |a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
@results = Kaminari.paginate_array(@things).page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

or

```
@things = @friend_things + @user_things
@things.sort_by! { |thing| thing.created_at }
@results = Kaminari.paginate_array(@things).page(params[:page]).per(20)
```