# Ruby: Paginate and sort across a large number of records

Tags: ruby

When simply displaying large amounts of data (over 100k records) my code works well, and I paginate on the server.

However, when I need to sort this data I'm stuck. I'm only sorting on the page, and NOT sorting on ALL the records related to this one customer.

How can I paginate but also sort across all the records of my customer and NOT simply sort the records returned from the server side pagination?

I'm also using [BootStrap Table](https://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) to display all my data.

Here is my code that gets all the customers:

```
  def get_customers
    @data_to_return = []
    @currency = current_shop.country_currency
    customers = current_shop.customers.limit(records_limit).offset(records_offset)#.order("#{sort_by}" " " "#{sort_order}")
    customers.each do |customer|
      @data_to_return.push(
      state: false,
      id: customer.id,
      email: customer.email,
      accepts_marketing: customer.accepts_marketing,
      customer_status: customer.customer_status,
      tags: customer.tags)
    end
    sort_customers
  end
```

And then this is the `sort_customers` method:

```
  def sort_customers
    fixed_data = data_to_return.sort_by {|hsh| hsh[sort_by]}
    customer_size = current_shop.customers.length
    if sort_order == "ASC"
      fixed_data
    else
      fixed_data.reverse!
    end
    render json: {"total": customer_size, "rows": fixed_data}
  end
```

In the above code you can see that `data_to_return` is coming from `get_customers` and its limited. But I don't want to return ALL the customers for many reasons.

How can I sort across all the records, but only return the paginated subset?

Comment: Maybe give this a shot: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

Comment: Yep that could work.. thanks! I also saw this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326855/rails-kaminari-how-to-order-a-paginated-array which sorts ALL the data before passing to Kaminari.. I'll try that!

Comment: Yep. Kaminari is really good. Enjoy coding. :)

Comment: Don't pass in things like `sort_by` directly as interpolated strings. Instead: `sort_by => sort_order`.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually sort at the model/query level, not at the ruby level.

The difference is basically:

```
# sort in ruby
relation.sort_by { |item| foo(item) }

# sort in database - composes with pagination
relation.order('column_name ASC/DESC')
```

In the first case, the relation is implicitly executed, enumerated and converted to array *before* calling `sort_by`. If you did pagination (manually or with kaminari), you will get just that page of data.

In the second case, you are actually composing the `limit`, `offset` and `where` (`limit` and `offset` are anyways used under the hood by kaminari, `where` is implicit when you use associations) with a `order` so your database would execute

```
SELECT `customers`.`*` FROM `customers`
  WHERE ...
  OFFSET ...
  LIMIT ...
  ORDER BY ...
```

which will return the correct data.

A good option is to define scopes in the model, like

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  scope :sorted_by_email, ->(ascending = true) { order("email #{ascending ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'}") }
end

# in controller
customers = current_shop.customers.
  limit(records_limit).
  offset(records_offset).
  sorted_by_email(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve sorting and paginate issue using Data Tables library, which is client side. It's a Jquery library. Using this you need to load all data into page, then it would work very well.
Below are the references please check.
[Data tables jquery libray](https://datatables.net/)

[Data tables gem for rails](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails)

You can try these, they will work very well. You can customise it as well

If the answer is helpful, you can accept it.

Comment: datatables won't help at all to sort 100k elements, because it would need to have all the records downloaded to the browser.

Comment: Guys, why did you down voted answer.You can get data using ajax also and don't need load data to browser. It gives you flexibility of sorting, filtering and downloading of files. You can refer below links for data tables using ajax  https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails

Comment: The OP does not know how to apply sorting in DB. Even with datatables, you can set up an ajax endpoint, and you still need to provide your sorted _and_ paginated results on the ajax response. The OP question is how to _actually_ sort and paginate at the same time.